# Show only three Divs at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a function that will show only 3 divs at once and when user click next it will show him next 3. The previous button needs to show previous 3 divs. Divs are created automatically by the user. When they type in the input field, it gets decided how many divs are going to be created.

Divs are created like this

```
document.getElementById('dropoptions').addEventListener('input', function () 
  {
    var select = $('#dropoptions').val();
    var number = $('input').val(); 
    $('.result').remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < number ; i++) {
    container.innerHTML += `<div class="result">${select}</div>`; 
  }
});
```

This function is supposed to show only 3 divs at once but when I click right(to show next) they all disappear.

```
$("#container .result").slice(0,3).show(); 
    $("#right").click(function(e) {

    var items = $('#container .result:visible').hide().last();

    var nextItems = result.nextAll().slice(0, 3);

      if (nextItems.length === 1) {
        nextItems = $("#container .result").slice(-3);
    } 

     if (nextItems.length === 0) {
        nextItems = $("#container .result").slice(0, 3);
    } 

    nextItems.show();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: also css file for container and item is #container .result {
      display: none;
  }

Comment: Can you please add fiddle and make runnable code snippet?

Comment: I am using ejs template with node

Comment: @JKshort you don't need node to create a demo of this and it would be really helpful in crafting an answer!

Comment: Any reason for not using existing carousel libraries? You can find some @ https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/carousel/

Comment: When is `result` defined?

Comment: ok i will make fiddle now

Comment: You don't need "fiddle" ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)) to make a runnable code snippet. Stack Overflow [supports](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) creating a runnable HTML/JS snippet inside a question by clicking that button on the toolbar with '<>' inside a document. It's better than a JSFiddle link because the code is right inside the question and can't be lost.

Comment: Can i add codepen link so people can see whole thing? @RoryO'Kane

Comment: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/) is basically the same as JSFiddle. You're allowed to post links to runnable code examples on those sites, and doing that is a good thing if it means we can see the current version of your web page and try editing it. But unless you have strong feelings about liking Codepen's or JSFiddle's interface more than Stack Overflow's, it's recommended to put your runnable web code directly into the question on Stack Overflow by editing the question, clicking the "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet" button in the toolbar, and pasting the code in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `result` instead of `items` to target the next elements. Use the following instead:

```
$("#container .result").slice(0,3).show(); 
$("#right").click(function(e) {

    var items = $('#container .result:visible').hide().last();

    var nextItems = items.nextAll().slice(0, 3);

    if (nextItems.length === 1) {
        nextItems = $("#container .result").slice(-3);
    } 

    if (nextItems.length === 0) {
        nextItems = $("#container .result").slice(0, 3);
    } 

    nextItems.show();

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9rzg2xy/)

Comment: when i type 5 it works as expected but when i type anything more it just show 3 divs.